# How to pass a bidimensional array as an argument to a function?

Tags: c++, arrays, function, multidimensional-array, function-pointers

I'm trying to make a function that displays a certain matrix;
 That's what I've tried to do:

```
void print(int n,int a[n][n])
    {
        for(int i=1;i<=n;i++)
        {
            for(int j=1;j<=n;j++)
            {
                cout<<a[i][j];
            }
            endl;
        }
    }
```

I know it's not correct but I don't have a better idea. Please help me!

Comment: Please tag your question with the language.

Comment: I guess its C++, but you are right. He should tag the language.

Comment: `endl;` doesn't do anything. You probably meant `std::cout << std::endl;`.

Comment: @aschepler I was going to say something but my tired brain missed the endl all by itself.

Comment: this does not relate anything to function pointers, so please remove that tag

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem might be the fact that your `i` and `j` indices start at 1 and not zero.
Try something like the following:

```
int a[m][n];
for (int i=0; i<m; ++i){
    for (int j=0; j<n; ++j){
        cout << a[i][j];
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
void print(int array[][n],int n){

  for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
      for(int j=0;j<n;j++){
          cout<<array[i][j];
      }
  cout<<endl;
  }
  return ;
}

print(array,size)
```

Answer (score 0):

`void print(int n, int a[n][n])` turns in fact into `void print(int n, int a[][])`

If the size is known you may use:

`void print(int (&a)[42][42])`

or in a generic way:

```
template <int N, int M>
void print(int (&a)[N][M])
{
    for (int j = 0; j != M; ++j) {
        for (int i = 0; i != N; ++i) {
            std::cout << a[i][j] << " ";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Note: index goes from 0 (inclusive) to N (exclusive).